# Bash - combine text and first page of .tiff file on one pdf page

Tags: bash, pdf, converters, tiff

I have a text file (~20 lines) and a (sometimes multi-page) .tiff file

the goal is to get ONE A4 pdf page where I have the content of the textfile and then the first page of the tiff file below (with the size adjusted to the space left if possible, else with a fixed resolution)

The text has always the same lenght and the tiff file contains A4 pages.

The system is a headless centOS

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the tools provided with the `libtiff-tools` package.

I would use `tiffsplit` to get the first page from the multi-page tiff and then possibly use `tiffcrop` to place the portion of it that you want at the bottom of your destination page.

To convert the text, I would use `enscript` to convert it to `PostScript` and then `ps2pdf`.

Comment: The problem is that i have to put the text and the tiff page on one side, all my tries resulted in a two page pdf file
Any idea for that?